# Odoo, see fields in XML but in grey

Tags: python, xml, customization, odoo

I want kow if it's possible to see the field with this value but I want this field can't be change or can't be included a value.

For example I want to display my product id of my application, the product_id is unique.
I want to see my product_id but the field must be not change (grey).

```
my .py
    _columns = {  
# Product
        'clicshopping_products_id': fields.integer('Product Id', size=5, help="Id product table of ClicShopping must be unique"),
    }

and my xml
<field name="clicshopping_products_id"/>
```

Do you have an idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [the `readonly` attribute](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html#semantic-components). You can do this either in your model or in the view (one of those in enough). Example of the latter:

```
<field name="clicshopping_products_id" readonly="1"/>
```

This won't change the fields color to gray, but it will made it uneditable, and that's what you ultimately want, if I understand your post correctly.

Comment: @loic richard Thank you. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.